# Will magnetic induction by permanent magnet be different from induction by electromagnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I was going through the magnetic induction topic and how we can induce a conductor by various methods. While going through the electromagnet method, I thought that the conductor placed near the electromagnet should be under the influence of two different magnetic fields. One from the electromagnet itself, of course, while the second is from the current flowing in the electromagnet because charge in motion generates a magnetic field. By this definition, shouldn't the induction by permanent magnet and induction by electromagnet be different? Because in permanent magnet there is only one magnetic field while the electromagnet has two different magnetic fields. If not, then please elaborate your answer. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why should the magnetic field of the electromagnet have tow different fields? The magnetic field from the electromagnet itself is the one arising from the current in it.

Comment: If that's the case, what's the purpose of the ferromagnetic solenoid core? We could just take a wire with closed circuit and have N number of turns for the magnetic field.

Comment: have you heard of the difference between the $H$ and $B$ fields, such as their sources and effects?

Comment: No. As a matter of fact, I don't even know what are H and B fields